# Styling Magento Blocks

Tags: magento

I have added the new products block to my homepage using the following code

```
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="homepage.newproducts" as="homepageNewproducts" template="catalog/product/new.phtml">
```

I have also set the product and column count for this custom layout as follows

```
<action method="setProductsCount"><count>6</count></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>homepage_layout</layout><count>3</count></action>
```

My question is, is there an easy way to add markup or a class or identifier to the block to enable me to style it. I know I could use the body class that magento applies and maybe the products-grid class, but what i'd really like to do is create some generic styling for 3/4/5 column grids and then be able to simply change the xml to the new column count and have that shown correctly on the frontend.

I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score -1):

Try those:

```
<action method="setHtmlClass"><value>class</value></action>
<action method="setElementClass"><class>class</class></action>
<action method="setValueProperties"><value>class="class"</value></action>
<action method="setGridHtmlClass"><value>class</value></action>
```

If this doesn't work another option would be:

1. [Overwrite](http://magedev.com/2009/06/03/magento-overriding-model-block-or-helper/) block catalog/product_new with your custom rewrite.
2. Add method addClass to your rewritten class.
3. In template call method getClass.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jevgeni, but I realised the easiest way was to just ammend my local template catalog/product/new.phtml. I added a css class using $_columnCount so I can style depending on how many columns the ul consists of.

Comment: Yeah, overwriting the local template was the best option ;)